# cannot find elements on jsp page (java selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

I cannot find any elements using selenium for a jsp page.
I tried print out the page source, but it seems to not have any head or body. When I inspect the page source manually through the browser, I was able to see the elements. 
Can someone tell me why selenium sees a different page source than when you do it manually? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Show your coding attempt and some HTML in your original post, please.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pain. I am building tests for an ExtJS website, and the IDs, Names, and other commonly used selectors are all generalized and change almost every time the page loads.

There are two good ways to deal with this issue.

Flaky solution (and the one I started with):
Use a `By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'TEXT ON CONTROL')]")` type of statement to find the controls. 
The reason this is flaky is that sometimes the findelement will see multiples of a control even when it is all the exact same control on the page.

Better solution (and the one I ask my devs to assist with when the tests flake out):
Have your devs add a `data-test = 'CONTROL NAME'` attribute to the controls. This will let you use a specific identifier that most JSP compilers ignore and leave alone.